# Botones redondeados en android

Tags: android

Tengo esto:

En drawable un fichero llamado: boton_redondo.xml cuyo contenido es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#F5D0A9"/>
    <corners android:radius="20dip" />
</selector>
```

En el botón que está incluido en el layout tengo:

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Modificar"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:background="@drawable/boton_redondo"/>
```

El resultado es que sale el botón sólo con la palabra Modificar, sin fondo ni nada, como si fuese un TextView.

Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias anticipadas.

Un saludo

Comment: El problema es que tu drawable es incorrecto debes usar shape en lugar de selector, usa como ejemplo el drawable de mi respuesta. Te recomiendo ver la documentación, saludos! :)

Answer (score 14):

Para lo que deseas lograr, no se usa un **[StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) (selector)** se usa un **[ShapeDrawable](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html) (shape)** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>    

    <stroke android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"/>

    <padding android:left="1dp"
             android:top="1dp"
             android:right="1dp"
             android:bottom="1dp"/> 

    <corners android:radius="30px"/> 
</shape>
```

selector, es usado cuando deseas crear un [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html). Para crear un drawable para generar bordes redondeados en tu botton debes usar un [ShapeDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html).

Puedes revisar la documentación de los tipos de drawable usados en android y su estructura:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Como ejemplo el .xml anterior lo guardamos dentro del folder `/drawable` con el nombre `borde_redondo.xml` y en nuestro botón lo cargamos como background:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRedondo"
    android:layout_width="159dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="bordes redondos"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="@drawable/borde_redondo"/>
```

Tendremos como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]