# Button con borde redondo Android Studio

Tags: android, botón, radiobutton

Como podría poner en Android Studio un Button con los bordes redondos?

Gracias.

Comment: Duplicado de: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/9068/botones-redondeados-en-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
    android:radius="0.1dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
    android:topRightRadius="7dp" />

<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#E8E6E7" />
```

Esto sería el shape.xml

Y aquí añades el botón

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/my_shape"
    android:text="Botón" />
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, me ha servido mucho.