# ¿como puedo lograr borde redondeado para un EditText?

Tags: android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me gustaría saber como lograr esto con un `editText` no encuentro la forma, no encuentro información alguien que me ilumine pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo_degradado"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

No puedes aplicar directamente shapes XML ya que no tendrás el efecto degradado que deseas para el borde, por eso debes tener una imagen PNG dentro de drawable que sea tu fondo y así apliques el efecto que deseas.

Answer (score 2):

#### EditText con bordes redondeados.

Similar a otras vistas como un `Boton` o `TextView`, como este ejemplo:

[Botones redondeados en android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/9068/botones-redondeados-en-android)

en el caso de un `EditText`, puedes usar un **[ShapeDrawable](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html) (shape)** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>    

    <stroke android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"/>

    <padding android:left="1dp"
             android:top="1dp"
             android:right="1dp"
             android:bottom="1dp"/> 

    <corners android:radius="30px"/> 
</shape>
```

El cual asignarías a tu EditText,

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="User Name"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/borde_redondo"/>
```

para obtener como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas hacer un archivo de configuración XML, donde añadas todas las propiedades que tendrá tu editText, y luego al editText le aplicas dicho diseño en la propiedad background.

[En esta web te ponen un ejemplo sencillo para hacer que un editText tenga los bordes redondos](https://karanbalkar.com/2014/10/create-custom-edittext-in-android/)

Este es un ejemplo de XML para poner los bordes redondos, solo habría que ponerle color a los bordes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="10dp"
android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="#F8F8F8"/>

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
    android:topRightRadius="4dp"/>

</shape>
```

Espero que te ayude