# Dar espacio al cursor de edittext?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

Este es mi editor de texto por defecto que se ve el cursor junto al borde del editor al iniciar la actividad, lo que trato de hacer es darle espacio al cursor hacia adelante.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como quiero que muestre mi editor por defecto al iniciar la actividad.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: como lograste darle esa forma? podrias poner tu xml?

Comment: Puedes agregar un padding pero considera agregar tu layout, sería útil para dar más opciones y tu pregunta sería muy útil a la comunidad! :), saludos!

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez ¿te interesa crear esa forma? revisa: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/99627/como-puedo-lograr-esto-con-el-edittext/99729#99729

Comment: gracias @Jorgesys

Comment: Saludos Igmer :-) @IgmerRodriguez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dale un `padding left` al EditText en xml o `padding start`.

Por ej:

```
android:paddingStart="8dp"
```

Answer (score 2):

Si estas usando un `shape` que asignas a tu `EditText` como background, puedes definir un `<padding`, por ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>    

    <stroke android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"/>

    <padding android:left="5dp"
             android:top="1dp"
             android:right="2dp"
             android:bottom="1dp"/> 

    <corners android:radius="30px"/> 
</shape>
```

---

También puedes asignar un `padding` izquierdo a tu `EditText`:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
```

---

o usar la propiedad [android:paddingStart](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:paddingStart) para definir un padding izquierdo

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="5dp" />
```

Son 3 opciones para obtener un espacio y que el texto no interfiera con el borde asignado a el `EditText`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]