# Poner bordes con color a un button (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, xml, botón

no se que ando haciendo mal en este codigo pero no me pone los bordes de color blanco y el fondo negro. Quiero hacer una linea que rodee el button de 5dp que sea blanca ya que el fondo es negro.

xml de la actividad

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonSendMail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="179dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_join_discord"
                android:text="Enviar "
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/messageID" />
```

xml button_join_discord del button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="@color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

y es que en el xml button_join_discord que tengo hecho me aparece con lineas el design

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal?

asi aparece en la app, sin bordes blancos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.turespawn"
    >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <meta-data
        
android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CL 
    ASS_NAME"
        android:value="yourpackagename.CastOptionsProvider" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/tr_logo_1920"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/tr_logo_redondo_1920"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TuRespawn">
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category 
    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: No entiendo, en tu imagen se ve que tiene los bordes blancos y el fondo negro, ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: Que en la app  no aparece asi

Comment: Bueno, antes que nada lo que necesitas es un shape que no esté dentro de un item, te adjunto una posible respuesta y me comentas que tal

Comment: Revisa [Botones redondeados en android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/9068/botones-redondeados-en-android/9074#9074)

Comment: Gracias me lo mirare aunque redondear botones me salia bien pero igualmente no esta de mas aprender aun mas jeje^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vamos a crear un nuevo `xml` de tipo `Shape` en la carpeta `Drawable` y se lo asignaremos a nuestro botón.

**diseno_boton.xml:**

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
<!-- Le daremos un radio de 5dp-->
    <corners
        android:radius="15dp"/>
<!--Establecemos el color de fondo-->
    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/black" />
<!--Establecemos el ancho de la línea y el color de la misma-->
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</shape>
```

Y para finalizar, lo asignamos al botón mediante el atributo:

```
    android:background="@drawable/diseno_boton"
```

**Actualización:**

cambia esto en tu manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar"
```

Comment: Sigue apareciendo igual, en el design del drawable aparece bien pero luego en la actividad el boton sigue igual, se aplica por ejemplo el corner radius que si funcionaba pero el stroke que es lo que le da la linea blanca no aparece

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar tu manifest?

Comment: Ya puse mi manifest

Comment: Modifiqué mi respuesta, dime que tal te va

Comment: Ha funcionado aunque la mita de mi app cambio de colores hahaha que sucedio? que aplica ese codigo?

Comment: Lo supuse, al crear un proyecto se le asigna un `Theme` por defecto que lo encuentras en la siguiente ruta: `resources/values/themes` dentro del mismo habrá código que puedes modificar. Puedes volver a modificar tu `manifest` volviendo a como lo tenías antes y modificar tu archivo `theme` o ir probando diseños mientras modificas la interfaz a tu antojo desde el `layout`

Comment: ah vale el modo oscuro y dia, por eso mi mi movil se cambian colores ahh, pues me has solucionado dos problemas hahaha muchas gracias ^^

Comment: De nada, que bueno que te haya servido :)

Answer (score -1):

[image: resultado]

//drawable/style_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item >
     <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                                  android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/transparente"/>
        <corners android:radius="300dp"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/teal_200"/>
    </shape>
   </item>
 </selector>
```

//Color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="transparente">#00FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe qué hace este código. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad porque suelen ser de poca ayuda para le usuario sin una explicación concreta de lo que hacen o cómo solucionan el problema. Por favor, edita la respuesta para añadir más detalles. Lee [answer] para más información.