No consigo que los Button de Android tengan redondeadas las esquinas
Estoy trabajando con Android Studio Koala. Pretendo que las esquinas de los Buttons sean redondeadas ya que me las pone cuadradas y no logro el objetivo.
Buscando he encontrado respuestas demasiado laboriosas y tengo la sensación de que debe ser mas facil.

¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento? Si compartes lo que has intentado, ayudarás a otras personas porque entonces no sugerirán lo que has intentado ya. O si ven algún problema en el código que compartas, podrán sugerir mejoras para que funcione. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información. Y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y de ese modo ganar tu primera medalla.

Recuerda agregar mayor información, en el sitio puedes encontrar información relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/9068/botones-redondeados-en-android  , recuerda revisar [ask], saludos,
